# Fabrication strategy to build larger version of our ESP

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, power-electronics, diesel

Our setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKuzshqjkYA 
The diesel generator exhaust is routed via our test setup. (notice the difference between ON/OFF states). Generator in test is similar spec as a 20kVA https://www.americasgenerators.com/20-kVA-Perkins-Diesel-Generator-Non-EPA.aspx

This is a project i've been pursuing for the past few months. This is to capture fumes from particle laden gas sources. (A lot of generators in developing countries aren't maintained properly, and their soot traps don't work too well).

This allows nanoparticles/pm 2.5 to be captured and segregated much more efficiently, without using any mechanical obstruction. We've also put in a self cleaning mechanical assembly inside to clean the collected particulate matter continually.

This is a lab scale build. Would like to understand how to go about building larger versions of this setup that can work on generators much larger which are a major source of urban pollution such as https://www.hindustantimes.com/gurugram/gurugram-will-get-new-air-quality-monitoring-station-to-keep-eye-on-pollution/story-xWgfUGHgLRLWjJD1FmLatJ.html

- What to keep in mind while scaling our mini setup?
- Should we attempt it ourselves, our rather talk to companies who might be interested in something like this and already comfortable with large fabrications.

We want to make 4-5 such setups and install it for a small pilot in Southern India where generators are used heavily.